# Win32::TieRegistry ws 64 bit on Windows 7 8 10

Tags: perl, registry

We have one perl script that write one file based on the Windows registry contents. 
The script need to be executed for the 32 and 64 registry hive.

Using this command "C:\stdperl\bin\perl.exe scriptname.pl" we process the 32 bit registry hive,
using this command "C:\stdperl64\bin\perl.exe scriptname.pl" we process the 64 bit registry hive.

We have : 
- This is perl, v5.8.7 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
- This is perl, v5.8.9 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

The restricted test case is :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::TieRegistry( ArrayValues=>0, Delimiter=>"/" );
use Config;

my ($chiave, $regKey, $key)="";

$chiave='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI';

$regKey = $Registry->Open($chiave, {Access=> 0x20019}); 
foreach $key (keys %$regKey){
    print"$key: " . $regKey->{"$key"} . "\n";
};
```

The above code do not work when executed with perl 64 bit on Windows 7/8/10.
Instead work fine when executed with perl 32 bit on all Windows version and work fine on 64 system with Windows server 2012, Windows 2003 Windows 2008.

Why?!

The script is very complex and old, undocumented and is the kind of script that nobody want to "touch" or "rewrite" so any ligth will appreciated a lot.

We do not get any error.

Simply when we run the script using 32 bit perl we get the following:

```
C:\>x:\stdperl\bin\perl 160609_t05.pl
Aster ODBC Driver/: Win32::TieRegistry=HASH(0x53b61a4)
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)/: Win32::TieRegistry=HASH(0x53b61ec)
...
omissis
....
Oracle in OraClient12c_32/: Win32::TieRegistry=HASH(0x53b627c)
SQLite3 ODBC Driver/: Win32::TieRegistry=HASH(0x53b621c)
```

When I run the script using the 64 bit perl I do not get any entry.

```
C:\>x:\stdperl64\bin\perl 160609_t05.pl

C:\>
```

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI registry there are ODBC drivers specification and there are entry on 32 and 64 hive registry.

Comment: _Win 2012_ is _Windows Server 2012_? You should [edit] your question and say so.

Comment: "do not work": Care to include an error message or describe how it's behavior differs from your expectations?

Comment: Start by checking what error you get!!!

Comment: We do not get any error. "Do not work" mean,.... do not print anytingh, I have added one example above

Comment: What Perl distro are you using?  Strawberry, ActiveState, DWIM......

Comment: we use ActivePerl, v5.8.7 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread &  v5.8.9 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Answer (score 0):

Using more recent version of ActiveState perl the problem do not happen.

ciao
GIovanni